# Neo4j Match with multiple relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need a MATCH where either relationship is true. I understand the (person1)-[:r1|:r2]-(person2). The problem I am having is that one of the MATCH traverse through another node. IE:

```
(p1:person)-[:FRIEND]-(p2:person)-[:FRIEND]-(p3:person)
```

So I want this kind of logic. The enemy of my enemy is my friend. And my friend is my friend. Output list of all the names who are my friend. I also limit the relationship to a particular value.

Something like:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:ENEMY{type:'human'}]-(myEnemy:Person)-[enemy2:ENEMY{type:'human'}]-(myFriend:Person)
OR (p1:Person)-[friend:FRIEND{type:'human'}]-(myFriend:Person)
RETURN p1.name, myFriend.name
```

I need one list that I can then do aggregation on.

This is my first posting....so if my question is a mess...hit me with your feedback and I will clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/) clause to combine 2 queries and also remove duplicate results:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ENEMY{type:'human'}]-(:Person)-[:ENEMY{type:'human'}]-(f:Person)
WHERE ID(p) < ID(f)
RETURN p.name AS pName, f.name AS fName
UNION
MATCH (p:Person)-[:FRIEND{type:'human'}]-(f:Person)
WHERE ID(p) < ID(f)
RETURN p.name AS pName, f.name AS fName
```

The `ID(p) < ID(f)` filtering is done to avoid having the same pair of `Person` names being returned twice (in reverse order).

[UPDATE]

To get a *count* of how many friends each `Person` has, you can take advantage of the new [CALL subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-post-union) syntax (in neo4j 4.0) to do [post-union processing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-post-union):

```
CALL {
  MATCH (p:Person)-[:ENEMY{type:'human'}]-(:Person)-[:ENEMY{type:'human'}]-(f:Person)
  WHERE ID(p) < ID(f)
  RETURN p.name AS pName, f
  UNION
  MATCH (p:Person)-[:FRIEND{type:'human'}]-(f:Person)
  WHERE ID(p) < ID(f)
  RETURN p.name AS pName, f
}
RETURN pName, COUNT(f) AS friendCount
```

Comment: Thanks and I did try that, but then lost the ability to do aggregation. I need to complete a count of friends after that. Mainly looking to see if there is a way to build the list in one MATCH statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "lost the ability to do aggregation"? What exactly are you trying to return?

Comment: A count of the number of distinct friends. Sorry for not clarifying earlier. Step one is getting a list to make sure it is working correctly. Then I want to count how many friends each person has. My final query will just output the numbers of friends each person has.

Comment: That's awesome! I'll give that a try. Thanks for your help!!!